# Pandas only get columns.str if Dataframe not empy?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this line of code:

```
catalog_df.columns = catalog_df.columns.str.replace(' ', '\n')
```

I'm getting the usual "`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string value`" but I (think I) know this is because my Dataframe is sometimes empty.

**My question is:** What is something concise to only apply the string replace when the dataframe *has* strings in the columns parameter? I was hoping there's something better than:

```
if not catalog_df.empty:
    catalog_df.columns = catalog_df.columns.str.replace(' ', '\n')
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge. What you have is very Pythonic. Or you can use `try` / `except` while catching `AttributeError`, but I have a feeling you don't want 4 lines.

Comment: just a remark, the dataframe can be empty and has columns, try with `catalog_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a '])`, it's empty but your line of code works.

Comment: Or the dataframe columns are only numbers.

Comment: `catalog_df.columns = [str(col).replace(' ', '\n') for col in catalog_df.columns]`